# Formatting ggplot axis using two scales simoultaneously

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale

What I am trying to produce is a plot (`ggplot2`) where two variables are plotted in the same x--axis, but one above and the other bellow the x-axis, but with (1) both up and down being absolute values, and (2) in non-scientific notation. Both tasks can be achieved individually using the functions (1) `abs`, and (2) `comma` from the package `scales`:

```
## data
rlength <- structure(list(Mapping = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("antisense", 
"sense"), class = "factor"), readlength = c(30L, 35L, 31L, 28L, 
34L, 32L, 24L, 22L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 23L, 26L, 33L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 
35L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 34L, 33L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 
20L, 24L), N = c(99854L, 7238L, 53523L, 146805L, 8743L, 28161L, 
18934L, 6872L, 117191L, 136601L, 35895L, 11110L, 70936L, 14873L, 
3807L, 4900L, 139893L, 74330L, 177004L, 173025L, 90852L, 137917L, 
76706L, 84552L, 104221L, 72414L, 73268L, 48112L, 51317L, 40638L, 
34869L, 64274L)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Mapping", 
"readlength", "N"))

library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

## plot1
ggplot(rlength, aes(x=readlength))+
   theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "sense"), aes(y=N), stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="blue")+
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "antisense"), aes(y=-N), stat="identity", colour="red", fill="red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=abs)

## plot2
ggplot(rlength, aes(x=readlength))+
   theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "sense"), aes(y=N), stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="blue")+
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "antisense"), aes(y=-N), stat="identity", colour="red", fill="red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
```

But trying to use the 2 together throws an error:

```
ggplot(rlength, aes(x=readlength))+
   theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "sense"), aes(y=N), stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="blue")+
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "antisense"), aes(y=-N), stat="identity", colour="red", fill="red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma, labels=abs)

Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  formal argument "labels" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

The question is:
Is it possible to combine these two formatter functions? If not, an solution on how to produce the plot I am looking for is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer and it was so obvious. All it is needed is a new function that combines `abs` and `comma`:

```
abs_commma <- function(x) {comma(abs(x))}

ggplot(rlength, aes(x=readlength))+
   theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "sense"), aes(y=N), stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="blue")+
  geom_bar(subset=.(Mapping == "antisense"), aes(y=-N), stat="identity", colour="red", fill="red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=abs_commma)
```

I am putting it here for future reference.

Comment: Ah, I'd just worked it out too! Opens up interesting possibilities for writing all sorts of label functions...

Comment: Indeed it does @MhairiMcNeill. I was aware that one could create our own formatting functions, but this is so very simple.